# Does setting a password on the postgres user mean that a password is required even when setting pg_hba.conf to trust?

Tags: php, linux, postgresql-9.2

I have done most of my PHP/PostgreSQL development under Windows 7, but am migrating to Linux.  I have recently installed PHP and PostgreSQL on Debian Wheezy, and was having difficulty connecting to my PostgreSQL database with the postgres user.  I found a post on stackoverflow that said to do the following:

```
template1=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

Initially, for the password, I used an empty string, which didn't work.  Next I used a text string, which allowed me to connect via pg_connect().

After doing more research, I found that altering the pg_hba.conf file and making the postgres user trusted was really what I wanted to do...  On making this change, I am still getting errors when a password isn't supplied via pg_connect() for the postgres user, so my question is:

Does altering the postgres user with a password cause pg_connect() to require a password even when the authentication method is set to trust?  When I connect via the command line using:

```
psql -U postgres
```

i have no problems...  The problems begin when connecting via PHP using pg_connect().

pg_hba.conf file:

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

PHP connection line:

```
pg_connect('host=localhost dbname=dev user=postgres');
```

Comment: show us your pg_hba.conf and you pg_connect string. (maybe you're connecting to 'localhost', which is different to connect directly on command line with psql -U postgres)

Comment: @Lorenzo, I edited the original post to add these lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `pg_hba.conf` to:

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

This will allow you to connect without password.

Remember to restart (or reload) postgresql after you edit `pg_hba.conf`.

In alternative, you can try to change your php code like this:

```
pg_connect('dbname=dev user=postgres');
```

This should work even without any change to `pg_hba.conf`.

**Explanation:**

You can connect to postgres via unix socket (suggested, faster) or via TCP/IP. The first and second line in `pg_hba.conf` are relative to socket, the third to ipv4 and the fourth to ipv6. If you specify localhost in your code, you're connecting via TCP/IP (ipv4), and that's why it didn't work and it asked you the password.

If you connect by console just with `psql -U postgres`, you're using unix socket, and that's why it worked without password.

Don't worry, even with changed configuration only local connection will be granted access with no password.

Comment: i will try it this evening US time.  I am away from that PC at the moment.  I will let you know how it goes then.